# Not getting desired output in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

I am firing a query in mysql but not getting desired output.
this is the code:

```
select team_name,
       sum(semis.points+final.points) as final_points 
from semis 
inner join final on semis.sid=final.sid 
inner join teams on teams.tid=semis.tid 
group by semis.tid 
   union 
select team_name,
       semis.Points 
from semis 
inner join teams on semis.tid=teams.tid 
left join final on semis.sid=final.sid 
where final.sid is null;
```

OUTPUT:

```
+-----------------------+--------------+
| team_name             | final_points |
+-----------------------+--------------+
| BioTech & BioChem     |            7 |
| Chemistry             |            7 |
| Botany & Zoology      |            7 |
| Physics & Electronics |           17 |
| BCA                   |           19 |
| BCOM                  |           11 |
| Gujarati              |           10 |
| English               |           10 |
| Economics             |           20 |
| BCOM                  |            3 |
| Chemistry             |            3 |
| English               |            3 |
+-----------------------+--------------+
```

and the result i want to fetch

```
+-----------------------+--------------+
| team_name             | final_points |
+-----------------------+--------------+
| BioTech & BioChem     |            7 |
| Chemistry             |           10 |
| Botany & Zoology      |            7 |
| Physics & Electronics |           17 |
| BCA                   |           19 |
| BCOM                  |           14 |
| Gujarati              |           10 |
| English               |           13 |
| Economics             |           20 |
+-----------------------+--------------+
```

Adding last 3 values to english,bcom,chemistry increasing it by 3 and making a total of BCOM: 14, Chemistry:10 , English: 13

Comment: Move the sum to an outer query, where you union in a subquery.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sample data you posted and the expected results it looks like you  can do it without `UNION`, by left joining `final` and with `coalesce()` for `final.points`:

```
select team_name, sum(semis.points + coalesce(final.points, 0)) as final_points 
from semis 
inner join teams on teams.tid=semis.tid 
left join final on semis.sid=final.sid 
group by semis.tid
```